# Git command executed in Docker container fails on server but not locally

Tags: git, docker, git-clone

I'm configuring a Satis Docker image and I encounter an error when trying to refresh the packages:

```
Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@git.domain.com:amp/support/db.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-domain.com-amp-support-db.git/'  
                                                                                                                                                            
  Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-domain.com-amp-support-db.git'...                                                      
  error: cannot create async thread: Operation not permitted                                                                                                
  fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off sideband demultiplexer
```

The strange thing is that the command works without any problems when running the image on my local Docker machine.

Things I tried:

- Tried from within the container on the server:

  - `ssh -T git@domain.com` -> Success
  - Tried Git command `git clone --mirror -- 'git@git.domain.com:amp..` from the error directly. -> Same error
  - Tried cloning the repo from the mirror to `/tmp`. -> Failed with same error.
- Tried from within the container running on my local Docker machine:

  - Tried the satis `build` command. -> Success
  - Tried the satis `build` command but with the certs of the server. -> Success
- Checked server resources. -> CPU and memory are around 15%.
- Checked versions of Docker and Git between local and server

  - On server:

    - Docker engine: 20.10.7
    - Git: 2.7.1
  - Local:

    - Docker engine: 24.0.2
    - Git: 2.25.1

Comment: Reading through [this github issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9888#issuecomment-1383684675) the final explanation there is that it has to do with the docker version. As your server uses an older version of docker, are you able to test on some other machine with the same docker version instead of your newer one?

Comment: You say "inside the container"; are you trying to start the application, then update its source code while it's running?  I'd normally expect to run `git` operations like this on the host only, then `docker build` a new image and `docker run` a new container.

Comment: @SebDieBln Thanks for your comment. I needed some time to do the server changes due vacation/work. Upgrading the version of Docker fixed the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze No I'm not updating the "baked" source code of the image. The Docker image is a server which has the software (Satis) which pulls Git repos every x minutes to build up an Composer Repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why this is the solution, but upgrading Docker to the latest version fixed the problem.